# Changing Background Color on Weekends

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that I need to change the background color (ex. gray) if the Day falls on the weekend (highlighted) in yellow. Have the code below that I have placed in row fill, but did not work. The yellow is manually colored.

```
iif((weekday(Fields!row_date)=6 or Fields!row_date=7s!TranDate=7) TranDate=Nothing),"LightGrey","Transperent")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the expression properties for the row input the following code:

=iif(Weekday(Fields!row_date.Value)>= 6 , "Yellow","Transperent")

Comment: Thanks Philip Webb very helpful.